# Creating a die program between two players

Tags: java

I wrote this code. The problem is that the player n1 is always the winner. Can anyone help me with this exercise?

```
public class Devoir9 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        int result = 0;
        Random r = new Random(6);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {    
            result = r.nextInt(6);
            result++; // result= result+1 or result++ sont les mêmes.
            // System.out.println(" you rolled :" + result);

            if (result == 6) {    
                System.out.println(" Player A is  winner " + result);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " SPELARE 1 VINNER  ");
            } else if (result != 6) {    
                System.out.println(" Player B and A are loosing  " + result);    
            }     
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Giving a seed to `Random` (here: 6) makes it return always the same sequence of "random" numbers. Omit the seed.

Comment: Also `r.nextInt(6)` will return a value from 0 to 5. Try `r.nextInt(6) + 1`.

Comment: There is no need for `else if  (result != 6)` 
The else part is only entered when the if part evaluates to false. in your case if `result == 6` evaluates to false. So if `result!=6`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are defining a hardcoded seed 6 for the Random instance. Do not define a number because you will get the same results every-time with that specific seed. The reason an user wants to add a seed to the random instance is usually for testing code and they want the same "random" values.

```
Random r = new Random();
```

Comment: If you find this comment solving your issue, don't forget to check this as answer so future viewers can also get their problems solved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're exactly trying to do with the for.
But this will just execute 6 times:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        result = 1 + (int)(6 * Math.random());

        if (result == 6) {
            System.out.println(" Player A is  winner " + result);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " SPELARE 1 VINNER  ");
        } else { //the second if was redundant
            System.out.println(" Player B and A are loosing  " + result);
        } 
    }
}
```

There's Math.Random() and the Random class. The Random class will do this

```
Random rand = new Random(); 
int value = rand.nextInt(6)+1; //0..5 + 1 = 1..6
```

The Math.Random() can be seen in the first Code Sample

Comment: Why switch to `Math.random()`?

Comment: First thing I went for, after that realized it and explained the other one too. Explaining multiple viable ways to solve something shouldn't be a problem, right? Math.Random() is closer to how it works in a lot of different languages, and yes, I know that in Java Random Class is more random (less predictable)

Answer (score -2):

Random numbers are generated by the device's clock value using algorithms.

As official documentation says

> public Random() Creates a new random number generator. This
>   constructor sets the seed of the random number generator to a value
>   very likely to be distinct from any other invocation of this
>   constructor.

So, in small possible number sequence, small differents based on milliseconds can generate same value more times. Using a Random constructor with a seed makes random number generated will be the same every time.

### Solution :

Simply remove the seed in the constructor

```
public class Devoir9 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        int result = 0;
        Random r = new Random(); //constructor without the seed
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {    
            result = r.nextInt(6); //generate random number between 0 and 6 (excluded)
            result++; //make result get value from 1 to 6 (inclused)

            // System.out.println(" you rolled :" + result);

            if (result == 6) {    
                System.out.println(" Player A is  winner " + result);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " SPELARE 1 VINNER  ");
            } else { //else if is useless because every other random number will be not == 6     
                System.out.println(" Player B and A are loosing  " + result);    
            }     
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Selling RNG as magic isn't a good answer. Your code solves the issue, but there's no reason to move the instance into the loop.

Comment: @IngoBürk The reason is writed in the Java Random class documentation. And I'll report here:

"public Random()
Creates a new random number generator. This constructor sets the seed of the random number generator to a value very likely to be distinct from any other invocation of this constructor." 
So, in small possible number sequence, small differents based on milliseconds can generate same value more times. Instatiating it on every cycles instead makes numbers will be always random.

Comment: And I did not say the RNG is magic.. I said in the answer that is based on the clock value.. so, same sequence in small milliseconds different generates same random value.

Comment: It's a bad idea to re-instantiate `new Random()` each iteration. The right thing to do is create it once before the loop. The important part of your answer is removing the seed -- calling `new Random()` instead of `new Random(6)`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant as well. As far as magic goes: you described RNG as very mysterious. It isn't. It's a well-documented process.

Comment: Lol @IngoBürk you're very finicky.. it was only a "joke".. but in this case, i'll edit my answer so you'll be happy